# Card with both image and background as header in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Working with some Bootstrap cards and I'm looking to create some cards with both a colored background and a circular image in the header, like so:

[image]

However, when I use some example code:

```
<!-- Background color -->
<div class="card-up aqua-gradient"></div>

<!-- Avatar -->
<div class="avatar mx-auto white">
  <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20%2831%29.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-responsive" alt="woman avatar">
</div>

<!-- Content -->
<div class="card-body">
  <!-- Name -->
  <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Martha Smith</h4>
  <hr>
  <!-- Quotation -->
  <p><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos,
    adipisci</p>
</div>
```

the result is missing some components:

[image]

Is this card setup possible in Bootstrap 4?  If so, what am I missing here?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes, possible. Please add CSS code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've prepared a very simple example for you. I hope that helps.

```css
.aqua-gradient {
  height: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(233, 242, 233, 0.9878326330532213) 0%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 51%, rgba(114, 156, 7, 1) 93%);
}

.image {
  margin-top: -150px;
}

.avatar-container {
  width: 90%;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="avatar-container text-center mx-auto">
  <div class="card-up aqua-gradient"></div>
  <!-- Avatar -->
  <div class="avatar mx-auto white">
    <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Avatars/img%20%2831%29.jpg" class="rounded-circle img-responsive bg-white p-3 image" alt="woman avatar">
  </div>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div class="card-body">
    <!-- Name -->
    <h4 class="card-title font-weight-bold">Martha Smith</h4>
    <hr>
    <!-- Quotation -->
    <p><i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, adipisci
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```